# Fourier transform with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, data-analysis

I have a set of [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzZ3xLk8sH4CZ3NUZU1jWFRRcTQ/view?usp=sharing). It is obviously have some periodic nature. I want to find out what frequency it has by using the fourier transformation and plot it out.

Here is a shot of mine, but it seems not so good.[image]

This is the corresponding code, I don't konw why it fails:

```
import numpy
from pylab import *
from scipy.fftpack import fft,fftfreq
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dataset = numpy.genfromtxt(fname='data.txt',skip_header=1)
t = dataset[:,0]
signal = dataset[:,1]
npts=len(t)

FFT = abs(fft(signal))
freqs = fftfreq(npts, t[1]-t[0])
subplot(211)
plot(t[:npts], signal[:npts])
subplot(212)
plot(freqs,20*log10(FFT),',')
xlim(-10,10)
show()
```

My question is:**Since the original data is very periodic looking, and I expect to see that in the frequency domain the peak is very sharp; how can I make the peak nicer looking?**

Comment: what's not right about it? what were you expecting?

Comment: @PaulH Why the peak so broad, I see that the period of the original data is very nice. How can I make the frequency more obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a problem of data analysis.

- FFT works with complex number  so the spectrum is symmetric on real data input :  restrict on `xlim(0,max(freqs))` .
- The sampling period is not good : increasing period while keeping the same total number of input points will lead to a best quality spectrum on this exemple.

EDIT.
with :

```
 dataset = numpy.genfromtxt(fname='data.txt',skip_header=1)[::30];
 t,signal = dataset.T
 (...)
 plot(freqs,FFT)
 xlim(0,1)
 ylim(0,30)
```

the spectrum is

[image: spectum]

For best quality spectrum , just reacquire the signal for a long long time (for beautiful peaks), with sampling frequency of 1 Hz, which will give you a [0, 0.5 Hz] frequency scale (See Nyquist criterium).

Comment: I got your first point, can you give a more detailed explaination of your second point?  should I replace "t[1]-t[0]" to "10*(t[1]-t[0])"? It is not nice either.

Comment: Just a check of my understanding. The sampling rate of yours is $1/(30*0.005s)=6.67Hz$, so according to Nyquist criterium. This sample rate gurantee that we can recover the information of the signal with frequency $f< 6.67/2=3.33Hz$. So acctually we should draw the x-axis from 0 to 3.4Hz.

Comment: However, I still don't understand the magic that you you choose less points can make the graph looks better, can you explain this part in your answer. Thank you!

Comment: it is just a zoom on the interesting part of the Spectrum. It seems to be no information after 0.5 Hz so the signal is oversampled. This graph looks better in linear scale for such data.