# Using NeuroSky's Mindwave Mobile(to measure brainwave) and Raspberry 3 to do FFT(to get certain frequency) with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, raspberry-pi, mindwave

I'm using *NeuroSky's Mindwave Mobile* and *Raspberry 3* to do FFT with `Python 2.7`.

Presently, I got raw data which is sampled brainwave data.

We can get raw data at 512 per sec. That means, Sampling Frequency is 512Hz,
but I don't know what to do. I found on the internet that I should first install `numpy` but I seem to be unable to get FFT working.

How can I use real-time data (raw data of measures using Mindwave Mobile) to do FFT?

Can you guys help me from first stage(install `numpy`) to final stage (do FFT)?

The following picture shows measured raw data, and next it's my code:

[image]

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time
import bluetooth
from mindwavemobile.MindwaveDataPoints import RawDataPoint
from mindwavemobile.MindwaveDataPointReader import MindwaveDataPointReader
import textwrap
from mindwavemobile.MindwaveDataPoints import EEGPowersDataPoint


if __name__ == '__main__': #외부에서 호출시
    mindwaveDataPointReader = MindwaveDataPointReader() #인스턴스 생성
    mindwaveDataPointReader.start()
    if (mindwaveDataPointReader.isConnected()):    
        while(True):
            dataPoint = mindwaveDataPointReader.readNextDataPoint() 
            #if (not dataPoint.__class__ is RawDataPoint):
                #print dataPoint        
            if (dataPoint.__class__ is RawDataPoint): 
                print dataPoint
    else:
        print(textwrap.dedent("""\
            Exiting because the program could not connect
            to the Mindwave Mobile device.""").replace("\n", " "))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this out which was talking about how to plot fft with numpy
[**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735153/plotting-a-fast-fourier-transform-in-python?answertab=votes#tab-top)

That's could be simple if you want to plot data offline, or have to create a loop to plot data in real time