# Unexpected FFT Results with Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft, dft

I'm analyzing what is essentially a respiratory waveform, constructed in 3 different shapes (the data originates from MRI, so multiple echo times were used; see [here](http://mriquestions.com/tr-and-te.html) if you'd like some quick background). Here are a couple of segments of two of the plotted waveforms for some context:

[image]

For each waveform, I'm trying to perform a DFT in order to discover the dominant frequency or frequencies of respiration.

My issue is that when I plot the DFTs that I perform, I get one of two things, dependent on the FFT library that I use. Furthermore, **neither of them is representative of what I am expecting.** I understand that data doesn't always look the way we want, but I clearly have waveforms present in my data, so I would expect a discrete Fourier transform to produce a frequency peak somewhere reasonable. For reference here, I would expect about 80 to 130 Hz.

My data is stored in a `pandas` data frame, with each echo time's data in a separate series. I'm applying the FFT function of choice (see the code below) and receiving different results for each of them.

SciPy (`fftpack`)

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.fftpack

# temporary copy to maintain data structure
lead_pts_fft_df = lead_pts_df.copy()

# apply a discrete fast Fourier transform to each data series in the data frame
lead_pts_fft_df.magnitude = lead_pts_df.magnitude.apply(scipy.fftpack.fft)
lead_pts_fft_df
```

NumPy:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

# temporary copy to maintain data structure
lead_pts_fft_df = lead_pts_df.copy()

# apply a discrete fast Fourier transform to each data series in the data frame
lead_pts_fft_df.magnitude = lead_pts_df.magnitude.apply(np.fft.fft)
lead_pts_fft_df
```

The rest of the relevant code:

```
ECHO_TIMES = [0.080, 0.200, 0.400] # milliseconds

f_s = 1 / (0.006) # 0.006 = time between samples
freq = np.linspace(0, 29556, 29556) * (f_s / 29556) # (29556 = length of data)

# generate subplots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(18, 16))

for idx in range(len(ECHO_TIMES)):
    axes[idx].plot(freq, lead_pts_fft_df.magnitude[idx].real, # real part
                   freq, lead_pts_fft_df.magnitude[idx].imag, # imaginary part

    axes[idx].legend() # apply legend to each set of axes

# show the plot
plt.show()
```

Post-DFT (SciPy `fftpack`):

[image]

Post-DFT (NumPy)

[image]

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/39z965y6unohn1q/fid?dl=0) is a link to the dataset (on Dropbox) used to create these plots, and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r3lo2g6wm9z3q44/Retrospective%20Gating.ipynb?dl=0) is a link to the Jupyter Notebook.

EDIT:

I used the posted advice and took the magnitude (absolute value) of the data, and also plotted with a logarithmic y-axis. The new results are posted below. It appears that I have some wraparound in my signal. Am I not using the correct frequency scale? The updated code and plots are below.

```
# generate subplots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(18, 16))

for idx in range(len(ECHO_TIMES)):
    axes[idx].plot(freq[1::], np.log(np.abs(lead_pts_fft_df.magnitude[idx][1::])),
                   label=lead_pts_df.index[idx], # apply labels
                   color=plot_colors[idx]) # colors
    axes[idx].legend() # apply legend to each set of axes

# show the plot
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Actually caught that just before you posted. Fixed in the edit. Thank you!

Comment: What is the mean value of the input series?  The plots show values that are around 0.99, but the vertical axis label says "normalized".  Are plots representative of the actual data being passed to the FFT functions?

Comment: With a Fourier transform, you generally not interested in the real and imaginary parts (unless you actually need phase information). So you should consider the magnitude of the complex values. This is the "energy" at a given frequency, and that will help you to determine which frequencies comtribute most to the signal. The other thing is that the signals have a mean value, so the zero frequency, i.e. constant, is significant and dominates the contribution from the other frequencies. Either subtract of the mean of the signal or use a logarithmic y-scale.

Comment: side question ... does that link you refer to http://mriquestions.com supply sample dataset files similar to the one you plot above ?

Comment: @ScottStensland likely no; my dataset is from a proprietary MR scanner. I can provide it to you, if that is helpful

Comment: yes if you could post this dataset or one similar it would help us/me to solve the issue

Comment: @ScottStensland edited with links to the dataset and Jupyter Notebook. Both should be available for download from Dropbox.

Comment: Did you try plotting `log(abs(fft))`?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I did. Please see the edit above.

Comment: That looks as expected. The DFT of a real-valued signal is symmetric. Typically you'd only look at the first half, which contains the frequencies 0 through Nyquist (==half the sampling frequency). In any case, you can now see that your DC component is way stronger than any other component, and it was hiding your actual data when plotting linearly. You now have a peak at the expected location, or?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting a Fast Fourier Transform in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735153/plotting-a-fast-fourier-transform-in-python)

Comment: That link might help you learn more about how to plot your DFT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out my issues.

[Cris Luengo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7328782/cris-luengo) was very helpful with [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735153/plotting-a-fast-fourier-transform-in-python), which helped me determine how to correctly scale my frequency bins and plot the DFT appropriately.

ADDITIONALLY: I had forgotten to take into account the offset present in the signal. Not only does it cause issues with the huge peak at 0 Hz in the DFT, but it is also responsible for most of the noise in the transformed signal. I made use of `scipy.signal.detrend()` to eliminate this and got a very appropriate looking DFT.

```
# import DFT and signal packages from SciPy
import scipy.fftpack
import scipy.signal

# temporary copy to maintain data structure; original data frame is NOT changed due to ".copy()"
lead_pts_fft_df = lead_pts_df.copy()

# apply a discrete fast Fourier transform to each data series in the data frame AND detrend the signal
lead_pts_fft_df.magnitude = lead_pts_fft_df.magnitude.apply(scipy.signal.detrend)
lead_pts_fft_df.magnitude = lead_pts_fft_df.magnitude.apply(np.fft.fft)
lead_pts_fft_df
```

Arrange frequency bins accordingly:

```
num_projections = 29556
N = num_projections
T = (6 * 3) / 1000 # 6*3 b/c of the nature of my signal: 1 pt for each waveform collected every third acquisition
xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0 / (2.0 * T), num_projections / 2)
```

Then plot:

```
# generate subplots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(18, 16))

for idx in range(len(ECHO_TIMES)):
    axes[idx].plot(xf, 2.0/num_projections * np.abs(lead_pts_fft_df.magnitude[idx][:num_projections//2]),
                   label=lead_pts_df.index[idx], # apply labels
                   color=plot_colors[idx]) # colors
    axes[idx].legend() # apply legend to each set of axes

# show the plot
plt.show()
```

[image]