# How to create a signal with certain sampling frequency and time?

Tags: python, audio, signals, signal-processing, sampling

I want to define a sampling frequency, e.g. `100 kSamples/second`, and a length for the audio sample, e.g. `4096` sampling points.

Then I want to calculate the number of spectral lines that I will get as well as the exact frequency that corresponds to each of those spectral lines.

I want to implement this in `Python`.

Can anyone throw out any ideas or links?

Comment: Before starting with looking at an audio signal, I would test my code with some simple sinusoids where you know how your output spectrum should look like. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735153/plotting-a-fast-fourier-transform-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some sampling frequency `fs` and `N` DFT bins, there are `N` frequency bins with the `k`-th one describing the contribution of the frequency

```
f_k = k * fs/N
```

---

The frequency bins `w_k = 2*pi*k/ N` of the DFT which are frequently discussed (e.g. in Wikipedia) are normalized in radians/sample, to get the real frequency, one has to take into account that `w_(N-1) = ws`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using a simple DFT:
 1. The number of the spectral lines is equal to the number of the samples. Mind that there are spectral lines in both positive and negative frequencies.
 2. The value and the implementation of the frequency vector calculation can be found here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html