# How can I compute the mean of a frequency band (mu, 8-13Hz)?

Tags: python

I need to compute the mean power of the mu frequency band (8-13Hz). I want to do it with the Fourier Transform, but I don't get the correct results.

*What I'm doing exactly is not important for the question, but maybe it helps understanding the code: I have many EEG-recordings of participants that imagine left or right-hand movement and I want to calculate their average mu power during rest (not imagining movement) and their average mu power during the imagery period (imaging left/right-hand movement) and then use the formula:
(power during imagery - power during rest) / power during rest*

However, the problem is, that I almost only get positive values, but they should be negative, so I think that there is a problem with the Fourier Transform. Can someone help?

My code looks like this:

```py
# left trial (C4)-------------------------------------------------

fs = 250. 

lrest = np.array(left_df.loc[left_df['Rest/Imagery'] == 'rest','C4'])
limagery = np.array(left_df.loc[left_df['Rest/Imagery'] == 'imagery','C4'])

low,high = 8,13 #mu waves 

### rest period 
        
#get amplitude of FFT 
fft_vals = np.absolute(np.fft.rfft(lrest))
        
#get frequencies for amplitude in Hz 
fft_freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(lrest),1.0/fs)
        
#take mean of fft amplutide for the mu band 
freq_ix = np.where((fft_freq >= low) & (fft_freq <= high))
meanlrest = np.mean(fft_vals[freq_ix])
        
### imagery period
fft_vals = np.absolute(np.fft.rfft(limagery))
        
fft_freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(limagery),1.0/fs)
freq_ix = np.where((fft_freq >= low) & (fft_freq <= high))
meanlimg = np.mean(fft_vals[freq_ix])
    
ERDS_left = (meanlimg - meanlrest)/meanlrest
        
ERDS_subject_left_fourier.append(ERDS_left)

# right trial (C3)--------------------------------------

rrest = np.array(right_df.loc[right_df['Rest/Imagery'] == 'rest','C3'])
rimagery = np.array(right_df.loc[right_df['Rest/Imagery'] == 'imagery','C3'])

### rest period    
fft_vals = np.absolute(np.fft.rfft(rrest))
        
fft_freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(rrest),1.0/fs)
        
freq_ix = np.where((fft_freq >= low) & (fft_freq <= high))
meanlrest = np.mean(fft_vals[freq_ix])
        
### imagery period
fft_vals = np.absolute(np.fft.rfft(rimagery))
        
fft_freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(limagery),1.0/fs)
freq_ix = np.where((fft_freq >= low) & (fft_freq <= high))
meanlimg = np.mean(fft_vals[freq_ix])
    
ERDS_left = (meanrimg - meanrrest)/meanrrest
        
ERDS_subject_right_fourier.append(ERDS_right)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I've done Fourier transforms so I could be wrong. You're using np.absoloute which could explain why you're getting only positive answers.

If you're looking at fourier transforms have you heard of scipy? The documentation is linked  [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/fft.html).

There is a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735153/plotting-a-fast-fourier-transform-in-python) on using scipy to plot a fourier transform I'm not too sure on the usefullness as my Physics days are long gone but hopefully the code is relevant

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I thought about that as well, but without np.absolute I get values like (-0.29669067291439893+0.7540383272335334j) and I can't work with those (or at least I don't know how, because I can't interpret them as numeric values). I already tried the scipy.fft but I will take a look at it again.

Comment: Is this [link](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/42812/calculating-power-in-frequency-band-using-power-spectral-density) of any use? Are you definitely sure you should be getting negative answers?